# Meaning of src, public, and build folders

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

I have recently started with programming, and I've just purchased a reactJs template, and the content comes ordered within folders named **src**, **public** and **build**; can you explain to me the reason of those folders? How does a web app work with those folders?

I ask this because I believe those names for folders are a *de facto* standard in web app coding.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a simplistic rundown:

`public` means the web accessible root of the site. Basically whatever is in that folder can be opened from  browser address bar. Server won't provide user access to files outside public

`build` is where compiled version  of assets are placed when you run npm build. This is what will get delivered to user

`src` (short for "source") contains your working files that will be used later to create the build

Comment: I would also add that these folder names are typical, but not necessarily standard. It depends on how your build tool and web server are configured.

Comment: @charlietfl you mentioned in `public` that "Server won't provide user access to files outside public" and then in `build` you say that "This is what will get delivered to user".

If `build` is a folder outside of `public` then, what is it in `build` that gets delivered to user exactly?

Comment: @EstebanClouthier I'm really in need of that answer right now...